# Delayed Sink Creation in StreamInsight Server

Tags: wcf, streaminsight

I have queries with WCF enabled sources and sinks and using StreamInsight embedded in my project. It creates source when i am running my query. It is OK but it will not create sink until some data tuples come into source (and make it through to sink). Thus, my clients cannot connect to sink (via WCF) before input data come to my query. How can i solve this problem?!

Comment: Maybe it is related to Lazy Initialization!! I could not find a clue

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It is because of the Lazy Initialization. You should create separate WCF services and some sinks which send their tuples to preregistered wcf ports.